# I'm losing the type of a variable in a generic method when passing to a second generic method with varargs

Tags: java, generics

I guess it's probably best to start with the behaviour I'm looking at:

```
public class genericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "5318008";

        printClass(str);              // class java.lang.String
        callPrintClass(str);          // class java.lang.String

        printClassVarargs(str);       // class java.lang.String
        callPrintClassVarargs(str);   // class java.lang.Object
    }

    public static <T> void printClass(T str) {
        System.out.println(str.getClass());
    }

    public static <T> void printClassVarargs(T ... str) {
        System.out.println(str.getClass().getComponentType());
    }

    public static <T> void callPrintClass(T str) {
        printClass(str);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> void callPrintClassVarargs(T str) {
        printClassVarargs(str);
    }
}
```

Looking at `printClass()` and `callPrintClass()`, it seems like everything is working fine. `callPrintClass()` takes a generic argument and passes it along. `printClass()` recognises this variable by its correct type, not caring who is sending the parameter, and then does as it's supposed to and prints `java.lang.String`.

But when we try to use varargs, this stops working. I would expect `printClassVarargs()` to recognise it's argument is of type `String[]`, much like the method without varargs recognises the type of its argument. Notice also that this doesn't happen if I call `printClassVarargs()` directly (it's perfectly happy there to output `String`), but only when it's called by `callPrintClassVarargs()`, where it forgets the type of its argument and presumes it's getting an `Object`. I also realise I'm having to suppress a compiler warning here, which usually comes along when I'm trying to cast generics, but I'm not sure what exactly is going on there.

So my question is really two. What is the reason behind this behaviour? Is this some consequence of type erasure, or the way Java handles arrays? And secondly, is there any way around this?

This is only a simple example, of course. I'm not trying to print class names this way, but originally found the problem while writing an overloaded method to concatenate arrays.

Comment: I found similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varargs are syntactic sugar that translates to an array of the given type by the compiler. 
That means that a `method(Type arg...)` will become `method(Type[] arg)`.

In Java, you cannot create arrays of [Non-reifiable types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html) (types whose type information is lost by erasure). Therefore, a generic varargs such as `printClassVarargs(T ... str)` will translate to `printClassVarargs(Object[] str)`, effectively resulting in erasure of the type info. This is what you are observing in your test.

--- EDIT ---

To answer your question (cfr comments) on the difference between `printClassVarargs(str)` and `callPrintClassVarargs(str)` we could have a look into the bytecode of your test class for the needed clues:

```
public Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc #16; //String 5318008
   2:   astore_1
   3:   aload_1
   4:   invokestatic    #18; //Method printClass:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   7:   aload_1
   8:   invokestatic    #22; //Method callPrintClass:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   11:  iconst_1
   12:  anewarray   #25; //class java/lang/String
   15:  dup
   16:  iconst_0
   17:  aload_1
   18:  aastore
   19:  invokestatic    #27; //Method printClassVarargs:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   22:  aload_1
   23:  invokestatic    #31; //Method callPrintClassVarargs:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   26:  return

public static void printClass(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #40; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   aload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #46; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   7:   invokevirtual   #50; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   10:  return

public static void printClassVarargs(java.lang.Object[]);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #40; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   aload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #46; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   7:   invokevirtual   #59; //Method java/lang/Class.getComponentType:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   10:  invokevirtual   #50; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   13:  return

public static void callPrintClass(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokestatic    #18; //Method printClass:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   4:   return

public static void callPrintClassVarargs(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   anewarray   #3; //class java/lang/Object
   4:   dup
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   aload_0
   7:   aastore
   8:   invokestatic    #27; //Method printClassVarargs:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   11:  return

}
```

Observe on main#12 that a new String[] of your string obj is created to be used as parameter for `printClassVarargs()` and `callPrintClassVarargs()`

On main#19 `printClassVarargs` is called, with the created String[] as parameter. This results in `printClassVarargs` knowing the type of that object at runtime. This type was preserved.

On main#23  `callPrintClassVarargs` is called, also with the created String[] as parameter. Then on `callPrintClassVarargs#1` a new array is created. This time, no type information is available from the generic type declaration, so a new Object[] is created. The String[] is stored in this array and on `callPrintClassVarargs#8` passed to `printClassVarargs`, which now has to work on an Object[], whose componentType is object.

As you can observe, the type of your parameter got erased when passed to the generic parameter of `callPrintClassVarargs(T str)`.

QED

Comment: I'm not quite sure on that. if you call <code>printClassVarargs("two", "strings")</code>, it will print <code>String</code>, not <code>Object</code>. It's definitely got some idea what kind of array I'm passing to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem boils down to the inability to create arrays of generic type.  If `callPrintClassVarargs` is modified to explicitly create a new array instance and pass it to `printClassVarargs` then the underlying issue becomes explicit.

```
// doesn't work, gives compiler error (cannot create array of generic type)
public static <T> void callPrintClassVarargs(T str) {
        printClassVarargs(new T[]{str});
}

//This works
public static <T> void callPrintClassVarargs(T str) {
        printClassVarargs(new Object[]{str});
}
```

[What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) -
This question deals with why it is not possible to create arrays of generic type, maybe the same explains this issue as well.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I guess I didn't know this is how varargs work; I had always imagined that it was them creating the arrays. But if the array is created by the caller, then as long as the caller knows the type there is no problem, we get the right one.