# Why is varargs (Class<? extends Throwable>... t) "unchecked or unsafe" operation?

Tags: java, exception, generics, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

Ok so I'm calling a method with a signature `(Class<? extends Throwable>... exceptions)` and I get a "File.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations" warning here in the main method:

```
public class VarargsFun {
    public void onException(Class<? extends Throwable>... exceptions) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VarargsFun().onException(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to see that `IllegalArgumentException` does indeed extend `RuntimeException`, `Exception` and `Throwable`?

How should I properly amend my code to get rid of this warning?

I don't really feel like instantiating my exceptions... it seems nicer to use the `.class`

(dont want to use `@SuppressWarnings` either!)

Am using java 7. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Are you sure the warning's coming from `thenThrow` and not `when`?  How is `mockQuery` declared?  Is it a mock of a generic class?

Comment: Ok I've changed the code to a testable example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because varargs are actually just arrays, and [generics and arrays don't mix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817544/228171) (well), Java has traditionally given a warning when you call a method with a generic vararg type.  This is because the array is technically being created at the caller.

However, it soon became evident that arrays created solely to be passed to a varargs method did not suffer from the same danger as normal generic arrays from the *caller's* perspective, however the method itself that received the generic array could abuse them.  So in Java 7 forward, the warning appears on the method itself (in your case, `onException`) and can be suppressed by using the [`@SafeVarargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) annotation on the method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public void onException(Class<? extends Throwable>... exceptions) { }
```

If you're not in fact using the Java 7 language, or if you can't change `onException` (presumably because it's a library method) then you can safely use `@SuppressWarnings` to hide that warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new VarargsFun().onException(IllegalArgumentException.class);
}
```

If you suppress warnings in this way however, take care to isolate this one statement in its own method so that you don't accidentally suppress other future warnings.

Personally, I disable generic vararg warnings completely in my IDE, because they almost never indicate incorrect code from the point of view of the caller.

Comment: Read your answer again including the last paragraph. Thanks!

Comment: It's also weird that I also don't get sonar warnings from this. In any case, I added `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method. Thx again.

Answer (score 12):

It's easiest to understand if you realize that

```
new VarargsFun().onException(IllegalArgumentException.class);
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
new VarargsFun().onException(
    new Class<? extends Throwable>[]{ IllegalArgumentException.class });
```

i.e. the call site creates an array with the component type equal to the type of the varargs.

But of course, `new Class<? extends Throwable>[]` is not allowed in Java. So the compiler does `new Class<?>[]` instead and gives a warning.

Comment: Thanks newacct! I already accepted Mark's answer, but thanks also for adding yours.