# Scala generic method - No ClassTag available for T

Tags: scala, generics, scala-2.10

I'm relatively new to Scala and am trying to define a generic object method.  However, when I refer to the parameterized type within the method I am getting "No ClassTag available for T".  Here is a contrived example that illustrates the problem.

```
scala> def foo[T](count: Int, value: T): Array[T] = Array.fill[T](count)(value)
<console>:7: error: No ClassTag available for T
       def foo[T](count: Int, value: T): Array[T] = Array.fill[T](count)(value)
                                                                        ^
```

Thanks in advance for help in understanding what is wrong here and how to make this contrived example work.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To instantiate an array in a generic context (instantiating an array of `T` where `T` is a type parameter), Scala needs to have information at runtime about `T`, in the form of an implicit value of type `ClassTag[T]`.
Concretely, you need the caller of your method to (implicitly) pass this `ClassTag` value, which can conveniently be done using a *context bound*:

```
def foo[T:ClassTag](count: Int, value: T): Array[T] = Array.fill[T](count)(value)
```

For a (thorough) description of this situation, see this document:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/scala-2-8-arrays.html

(To put it shortly, ClassTags are the reworked implementation of ClassManifests, so the rationale remains)

Comment: Fascinating.  With 'import scala.reflect.ClassTag' this works.  Thanks.

Comment: People may find this instructive as well - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html - since ClassManifests are going away.

Comment: If we do any comparison of two values of type T in the function body, we need an `implicit` orderer parameter in additional to the `ClassTag` annotation.

Comment: I found this Java-oriented question helpful as well to understand why we don't need ClassTags for e.g. Lists, but Martin's SIP also hinted at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java