# not enough arguments for method toArray

Tags: scala, generics

The toArray call in following code does not compile

```
trait A[T] {
  def create:T
  def foo(a:Array[Int]) = {
    for(b <- a) yield create
  }.toArray
}
```

It throws the following errors:

```
not enough arguments for method toArray: (implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])Array[T]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.  
No ClassTag available for T
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sergey said, Java arrays need to know the type of T, but `T` is eliminated by type erasure.

In scala you can "preserve" a type information at runtime using a `ClassTag`.

Here's a more [in-depth discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921168/scala-generic-method-no-classtag-available-for-t) about arrays.

As per fixing it, you need to provide evidence of a `ClassTag` for `T`. Here's a possible solution:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait A[T] {
  def create: T
  def foo(a: Array[Int])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = {
    for(b <- a) yield create
  }.toArray
}
```

The implicit `ev` parameter is filled in automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to remove `toArray` call. Because you iterate over array so your result will be array too.

Comment: Where do I add ClassTag?

Comment: The result is of type ArraySeq. I want Array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't create an `Array[T]` without knowing `T`. The `ClassTag` is Scala's way of representing this information. The simple fix would be to change `trait A[T]` to `abstract class A[T: ClassTag]` (class is needed because traits can't have any constructor parameters, including implicit ones). If you then create it with a *specific* type, e.g. `class B extends A[Int]`, the compiler will insert the correct `ClassTag` itself, with a generic you need to pass the `ClassTag` through: `class C[T: ClassTag] extends A[T]`.