# How to shift arrays and matrices in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

Suppose I need to shift an array of integers to left and right.

```
val shl : Array[Int] => Array[Int] = a => (a drop 1) :+ 0
val shr : Array[Int] => Array[Int] = a => 0 +: (a dropRight 1)
```

Suppose also I need to shift a matrix of integers to left and right

```
val shlm: Array[Array[Int]] => Array[Array[Int]] = _ map shl
val shrm: Array[Array[Int]] => Array[Array[Int]] = _ map shr
```

and up and down

```
val zeros: Int => Array[Int] = n => Array.fill(n)(0)
val shum: Array[Array[Int]] => Array[Array[Int]] = m => (m drop 1) :+ zeros(m.length)
val shdm: Array[Array[Int]] => Array[Array[Int]] = m => zeros(m.length) +: (m dropRight 1)
```

Now I would like to *generalize* `shl` and `shr` to reuse them for shifting matrix up and down. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

type ArrayOp[T] = Array[T] => Array[T]

def shl[T:ClassTag](zero: T)(a: Array[T]): Array[T] = (a drop 1) :+ zero
def shr[T:ClassTag](zero: T)(a: Array[T]): Array[T] = zero +: (a dropRight 1)

val shlm: ArrayOp[Array[Int]] = _ map shl(0)
val shrm: ArrayOp[Array[Int]] = _ map shr(0)

val zeros: Int => Array[Int] = n => Array.fill(n)(0)

val shum: ArrayOp[Array[Int]] = m => shl(zeros(m.length))(m)
val shdm: ArrayOp[Array[Int]] = m => shr(zeros(m.length))(m)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the `ClassTag` means runtime reflection ?

Comment: Yes, the Scala runtime library needs the information about the concrete class to construct the array (see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921168/scala-generic-method-no-classtag-available-for-t).

Comment: Oh, I see ... Can I solve this problem without runtime reflection if I use another class instead of `Array` ?

Comment: Yes, you could use most collections from the Scala standard library. For your case a `Vector` might be most suitable as runtime representation since it has effectively constant time characteristics for prepend and append (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Comment: Great. Thank you again. I will try `Vector` instead of `Array`.