# Scala Generic MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, scala

The [mongo-scala-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver) has been updated recently, and I wanted to update my app ([link](https://github.com/ex0ns/telegram_XKCD_ibot)) to support the newly added [case classes](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.0/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/).

I'm currently having an issue with those case classes and do not find a way to solve it (proper way at least).

I have a trait named `Collection` in which I defined some generic queries than can be applied to any of my collections:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoCollection, _}

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Collection[T] {
  protected val DEFAULT_LIMIT_SIZE = 50
  protected val collection: MongoCollection[T]

  def insert(obj: String): Future[_]

  def get(id: Int) = collection.find(equal("_id", id)).first().head()

}
```

I also implemented in subclasses some collection specific queries, for instance

```
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Groups extends Collection[Group] with Database {

  override val collection : MongoCollection[Group] =   database.withCodecRegistry(Group.codecRegistry).getCollection("groups")

  override def insert(groupId: String) : Future[Group] = {
    val group = Group(groupId.toLong)
    collection
      .insertOne(group)
      .head()
      .map(_ => group)
  }

  def all =
    collection
      .find()
      .toFuture()

}
```

The issue comes from the `get` method of the `Collection` trait:

```
[error] Collection.scala:13: No ClassTag available for C
[error]   def get(id: Int) = collection.find(equal("_id", id)).first().head()
```

I'm pretty sure it comes from the fact that I use the trait type parameter as type for a MongoCollection, but I can't think of an other way to implement this.

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks

**EDIT**: By adding `(implicit ct: ClassTag[T])` to each method of the `Collection` trait, it seems to work, but I don't really like doing that...

**EDIT2**: It's also possible to put this `implicit ct` in the trait, and override it from subclasses:

```
trait Collection[T] {
    implicit def ct: ClassTag[T]
    ...
}
```

And in subclasses:

```
object Groups extends Collection[Group] with Database {
    override def ct = implicitly
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think here may be answer or at least hint -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921168/scala-generic-method-no-classtag-available-for-t

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this post, but I don't think it's that close to what I'm looking for. Indeed, in my case, it's the `find` method of mongoDb that require a `ClassTag` as implicit `def find[C]()(implicit e: C DefaultsTo TResult, ct: ClassTag[C])`, but there is no ClassTag available for a generic T

Answer (score 0):

Update: You need to implicitly pass `ClassTag` for `T` in get method of your collection trait.

```
def get[T : scala.reflect.ClassTag] {
    //...........
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because type parameters of traits can't be bounded.

Comment: here, T is not bounded, ClassTag is implicitly passed, Collection[T : scala.reflect.ClassTag] is similar to Collection[T](implicitly ct: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])

Comment: This is not what `scalac` is telling me: `[error] Collection.scala:7: traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds `: ...' nor view bounds `<% ...'
[error] trait Collection[T: ClassTag] {`. However it lead me to another solution (using `implicitly`) (I updated my question)

Comment: I didn't realize that, you should try passing implicit classtag to method instead as I have updated in answer. Anyway, I'm glad you found a workaround.