# Errors while using generics, arrays and compareTo()

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, compare, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a generic container and I **have to** use an array. I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

Here is a portion of my code :

```
class MinFo<T extends Comparable> {

private final T[] array;

MinFo(int size){
array = (T[]) new Object[size];

}

T get(){

if(this instanceof Comparable){

int tmpPos = getNotNull();
T tmp = array[tmpPos];
int pos;    
for(pos = tmpPos ; pos < array.length; getNotNull()){

    if(tmp.compareTo(array[pos]) > 0)
    tmp = array[pos];
}
```

which led me to remove the "extends Comparable" from the class declaration. Now I have a different error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
    if(tmp.compareTo(array[pos]) > 0)
          ^
symbol:   method compareTo(T)
location: variable tmp of type T
where T is a type-variable:
 T extends Object declared in class MinFo
```

It seems to me that I can't win. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Let us see your main where error occurs

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, or, at worst, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`?

Comment: @fge You are right, I had `<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object doesn't actually implement Comparable, so that declaration won't work.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java) that may be relevant. [And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation); I think they explain it better than I could.

Answer (score 5):

Well yes, this is the problem:

```
array = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

If you change that to:

```
array = (T[]) new Comparable[size];
```

then it should be okay. The thing is, the cast to `T[]` is only (at execution time) a cast to `Comparable[]` as the upper bound of `T` is `Comparable`.

Comment: When I implement your changes I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: not comparable`