# JUnit test case casting wrong elements in generic methods

Tags: java, generics, testing, junit, casting

I have 2 methods.

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] sort(T[] array) {}
```

And

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] sort(T[] array,
            Comparator<? super T> c) {}
```

Implemantation w/o any erros, but after JUnit test case i got an error on T[] s =...

JUnit says:

```
java.lang.object cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable;
```

In the test case JUnit gives me also this line next to the error:

```
assertArrayEquals(a1, ComparisonCountingSort.sort(ar1));
```

My question here is to know what i can fix here to have an succesful JUnit test case.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java. Now, what are you trying to do with the Array s? Is that code in your productive code or in the Unit test?

Comment: No,its the productive code. I post the Unit test case in start post.Thanks

Comment: @JamesRich you should accept one of the answers as correct if they worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an array of nulls of the correct type and length

```
T[] s = Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.copyOf(array, 0), array.length);
```

If you are ok with an exact copy, you can use

```
T[] s = Arrays.copyOf(array,  array.length);
```

Comment: I tested the second one. It works fine. Can you explain why it works in the methods?

Comment: Under the hood, this method also uses 'System.arraycopy'. The trick is how it creates an array with a generic type... This is done by finding the _Component Type_ of the incoming array 'array.getClass().getComponentType()' and dynamically creating a new array of the same type 'Array.newInstance(componentType)' - I find it quite useful to dive into the JDK source once in a while to understand what is really going on, and maybe using a JUnit test and/or debugger to see the details...

Comment: To clarify... This approach actually creates an array of the correct type, and in the calling code an attempt to cast the array to the non-generic type will work. If you 'new Comparable(...' This is actually a _Comparable_ array - you can add _any_ Comparable to it, so, you can't cast it to a specific type as it may contain something that is not that type...

Answer (score 1):

Since `T` is a type which extends `Comparable` it should be

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] s = (T[]) new Comparable[array.length];
```

Reason being an `Object` type cannot be cast to `Comparable` since `Object` IS NOT A `Comparable`

Comment: I changed it. Passed the test succesfully. 0,13 s I ask only if i have to change it on both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Collections of `object` cannot be casted to collection of `T`.
What is more you cannot do this: `T x = new T()`.
You can provide dependency to class that is able to create object of type `T`.
 To copy your `array` you can use `System.arraycopy`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I dont get the last part of your post. Maybe i post the whole implementation,maybe it is easier for me to understand.