# Declare an array of WeakReferences?

Tags: java, weak-references

I know how to declare an individual `WeakReference`, but what about an array of them?

```
    WeakReference<String> testWR;
    testWR = new WeakReference<String>("Hello");

    String[] exStrArr;
    exStrArr = new String[5];

    WeakReference<String>[] testWR2;
    //not working
    testWR2 = new WeakReference<String>[5];
    testWR2 = new WeakReference<String>(new String())[5];
    testWR2 = new WeakReference<String>()[5];
```

Could someone please tell me the proper syntax here? I'd sure appreciate it =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You can't create an array of a parametrized type (except unbounded wildcard types). Consider using a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead:

```
List<WeakReference<String>> testWR2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

This restriction on arrays is necessary for type safety reasons. For instance, consider the example given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/fineprint.html), which shows what would happen if arrays of parametrized types were allowed:

```
// Not really allowed.
List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10];
Object o = lsa;
Object[] oa = (Object[]) o;
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(new Integer(3));
// Unsound, but passes run time store check
oa[1] = li;

// Run-time error: ClassCastException.
String s = lsa[1].get(0);
```

> If arrays of parameterized type were allowed, the previous example would compile without any unchecked warnings, and yet fail at run-time. We've had type-safety as a primary design goal of generics. In particular, the language is designed to guarantee that **if your entire application has been compiled without unchecked warnings using `javac -source 1.5`, it is type safe.**