# Java - Creating array of an object with generic parameters

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So I know normally to create a generic array you could do:

```
E[] e = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

However I have a class `Entrant<K, V>` which has two generic parameters.
I can't seem to be able to cast an Object array to it.

Here is the full code and error at runtime

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LHashTable.Entrant;
    at HashTable.HashTable.<init>(HashTable.java:10)
    at Mainy.map(Mainy.java:32)
```

line 32 in Mainy :

```
HashTable h = new HashTable();
```

Hashtable code:

```
public class HashTable<K, V> {

    Entrant<K, V>[] _entrants;
    private static final int N = 16;

    public HashTable() {
        _entrants = (Entrant<K, V>[]) new Object[N]; //line 10
    }

}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do does not work. An `Object[]` is not an `Entrant<K, V>[]`, so you get a `ClassCastException`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java?rq=1

Comment: also.. Please follow standard Java naming conventions - camelCase for instance

Answer (score 4):

Casting `Object[]` to `E[]` is not guaranteed to work when you expose the array outside your class. Casting works in constructor because the type of the type parameter `E` is erased to `Object`, and the cast is effectively equivalent to:

```
Object[] e = (Object[]) new Object[10];
```

However, suppose your `HashTable` class provides a `K[]` array:

```
class HashTable<K, V> {

    K[] _entrants;
    private static final int N = 16;

    public HashTable() {
        _entrants = (K[]) new Object[N]; //line 10
    }

    public K[] getEntrants() {
        return _entrants;
    }
}
```

And you create instance of it, and gets the entrants from it:

```
HashTable<String, String> hashTable = new HashTable<>();
String[] entrants = hashTable.getEntrants();
```

That code will throw `ClassCastException` in the second assignment.

While in case of parameterized type array, casting would fail as it is erased to:

```
_entrants = (Entrant[]) new Object[N]; //line 10
```

Clearly an `Object[]` is not a `Extrant[]`. So that would fail to work. Rather than doing the cast, you can directly create an array of raw type:

```
_entrants = new Entrant[N];
```

and suppress the warning that comes.

**Also See:**

- [How to create a generic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863)
- [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/1679863)

Comment: or `new Entrant<?, ?>[N]` if you want to avoid raw types

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this is :

Every Entrant is an Object, but every object is not an Entrant. See, you are casting Objects to Entrants which won't work.