# Generics and Callable causing peculiar error

Tags: java, generics

While working on `generics` and `Callable`  i am getting following error:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to
>   capture#1-of ? extends Object[]

```
 public class Test {

    public Object m1(Callable<? extends Object[]> abc) throws Exception {
        return abc.call()[0];//Getting error here
    }
}
```

I am really not sure what is producing this error.

It would be great if some one share knowledge on this error as i am not able to understand it.

It is not duplicate of above mentioned question , Please check

Comment: @RobinTopper--No No its not duplicate, Please check again I am asking from generics context and not about extending A[]

Comment: This error is because method `call()` returns type `? extends Object[]` which can't be cast to array. If you change to `Callable<Object[]>` it works fine

Comment: Do you want to know "_what is producing this error_" or _how to solve it_?

Comment: Here is some background on the [interaction of generics and arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581313/2074605) and some [additional](http://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/2074605) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817544/2074605) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend an array. Just use `Callable<Object[]>`.

UPDATE:

Or, if it's the class of the elements that can be extended, You can do this:

```
public <T> T m1(Callable<T[]> abc) throws Exception {
    return abc.call()[0];
}
```

Comment: `? extends Object[]` let him call this method with any array (e. g. `Callable<Number[]>)

Comment: @StefanWarminski yes, I thought that was the idea, but he's doing it wrong (and so are you)

Comment: no, he's not. `return ((Object[]) abc.call())[0];` works fine. You're right that you don't write code that `Number[] extends Object[]` but the compiler does.

Comment: @StefanWarminski the correct way to do this is in my update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a little debugging from yourself

```
public class Test {
    public Object m1(Callable<? extends Object[]> abc) throws Exception {
        Object[] call = abc.call(); // Maybe your error is here
        System.out.println(call.length); // See what this returns
        return call[0];
    }
}
```

Also remember that when you say `//Getting error here`, tell us WHAT error you're getting.